# Sea ships and their space-time equations

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

On different days,  two sea ships and their space-time equations (coordinates in km and hours) were observed:

$ A: x ⃗=(12, -4)+t(8, 28)$

$ B: x ⃗=(10, -2)+t(10, 25)$

Find out whether the boats have different velocities or different courses.

My question: Since the coordinates are time and space, how do I plot these on a graph? Can I do the following:

For example for A, can I take 12 as $x1$ space coordinate and 8 as $y1$ time coordinate of one point. Then, take -4 and 18 for the other point so that could be the first vector?

And how can I calculate the velocity?

Thank you.

Comment: is this right that both Parameters are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Plug in $t=0$. $t$ multiplies the vector next to it, for example$(8,28)$ in case of $A$. You get for $A:$ $\vec x=(12,-4)$ and for $B$ you get $\vec x=(10,-2)$ Each pair is the starting coordinate. If you plug in $t=1$ you get for $A:$ $\vec x = (12,-4)+1(8,28)=(20,24)$ and similarly for $B:$ $(20,23)$